# printing doubles from a function outside of main

Tags: c, printf, double, function-prototypes

I am new to c and trying to use a function outside of the main function, I wanted to test what I was getting but found an error when I print the value from the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/*function prototype f*/
int f(double x);

/*main*/
int main(void){

   double x = 0.1;

   printf("the value is %.3f\n", f(x)); 
   printf("the value is %.3f", sqrt(1.0-(x*x))); 

   return 0;
}

int f(double x){
    double value;
    value = sqrt(1.0-(x*x));}
    return value;
}
```

This basic code finds a value from a given x that I want to later use in a loop. when I run this however I get the following output

> the value is -1.....
>   the value is 0.995

(… is a random sequence of
 characters)

I am not sure what the difference is in the function f and the actual value calculated inside the main function and why I am getting this issue

Comment: You’re converting the function result to an int - change the function declaration/definition so that it returns double rather than int.

Comment: Computation note: `sqrt((1.0-x)*(1.0+x))` will provide a more accurate answer, especially when `x` near 1.0.  To see, use values near 1.0 and `"%e"`.

Comment: tribo32, What compiler are you using that did not warn about `printf("the value is %.3f\n", f(x));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using int instead of double for your prototype. This should give you the right answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

/*function prototype f*/
double f(double x);

/*main*/
int main() {

    double x = 0.1;

    printf("the value is %.3f\n", f(x));
    printf("the value is %.3f", sqrt(1.0 - (x*x)));

    _getch();
    return 0;
}

double f(double x) {
    double value;
    value = sqrt(1.0 - (x*x));
    return value;
}
```